# What is significance of confirmation page before deleting a node?

Tags: hooks

I want to know what exactly usage of node confirm delete page except to avoid miss configuration.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The reason why Drupal asks for confirmation before deleting a node is that the operation cannot be undone: Once the node is deleted, Drupal cannot restore the deleted data.

Comment: This question is not Drupal-specific. It's a UX question for which the answer is true for every software.

Comment: thanks @kiamlaluno but I am asking about usage of that page. I mean we can apply delete feature by just clicking on node listing page but why to redirect on confirmation page. any idea ?

Comment: As kia said, this is a UX question, but the answer, presumably, is to make the user think about what he is doing and confirm the intent. Deleting a node is a non-recoverable (DB backups notwithstanding) process; if you had an accidental or mindless button press that could potentially wipe out hours of work it would make a bitter UX.

Comment: It is NOT just a UX question. The confirmation page has a very important function which is to prevent CSRF attacks. If there were no such a confirmation page, any attacker could forge a link in a webpage or email and if a user with enough permissions visits this malicious page or reads that mail, the node in question would be deleted without any confirmation and without the user noticing.

Comment: Think about the logout link `user/logout`, which has no confirmation page. If I would send you a mail attached with an image given a source like "http://yoursite/user/logout", you will be immediately logged out of your site as soon as you read my mail. The same would be possible for node delete action, if it didn't need to be confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

This is no t exactly Drupal specific, but I'll answer them anyway because one could miss a few reasons. Correct me if I'm missing any.

- It prevents accidentally clicking the delete button and actually deleting it.
- It provides security against CSRF attacks. If the node is deleted as soon as the node/xyz/delete page is loaded, an attacker can make an administrator open that URL, and the node will be deleted without his intention.

  - Because the specifications say so. http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2616.txt     GET requests should not make any *change* in data, so the request must be either a POST or a DELETE. Since Drupal forms only support GET and POST, we use the latter.